# ¿Cómo ordenar una cadena por oreden una cadena de caracteres alfabeticamente? Nota: no puedo usar sorted

Tags: python

```
    def ordenar_cadenav2(cadena:str)->str:
        posicion=len(cadena)-1
        mayor=posicion
        nueva_cadena_ordenada=""
        while posicion>=0:
            if cadena[posicion]>cadena[mayor-1]:
                nueva_cadena_ordenada+=cadena[posicion]
            elif cadena[posicion]<cadena[mayor-1]:
                nueva_cadena_ordenada+=cadena[mayor]
            elif cadena[posicion]==cadena[mayor-1]:
                nueva_cadena_ordenada+=cadena[posicion]
            posicion=posicion-1
        return nueva_cadena_ordenada
```

Este es mi código, organiza alfabéticamente cadenas como "cba" pero cadenas como "leomessi" no arroja un resultado correcto.

Comment: que resultado te arroja?

Comment: y por favor, los nombres de variables que sean representativos, mayor es la longitud de la cadena, longitud en realidad es la posicion que estas mirando, y contador en realidad es la cadena resultante... fijate eso...

Comment: En el caso de "leomessi" me arroja al ejecutar "issiiiii".

Comment: y si.. fijate que siempre estas comparando contra el ultimo (siempre contra mayor-1) y solamente haces una pasada a tu cadena, cuando un sort en general hace varias pasadas (Dependiendo el tipo de sort). yo te recomendaria que leas sobre metodos de sort. son bastante mas complejos que una iteracion..

Comment: Lo que sucede es que en la indicación del problema me indica que no puedo usar métodos como sort o sorted. Debo de resolver el problema tan solo valiéndome de ciclos while y for.

Comment: si. .lo entiendo a la perfeccion, y no te estoy diciendo que uses ninguno de esos metodos, si no que programes vos el sort como corresponde.. que es algo que todos hicimos al principio... y para eso tenes que leer como se hace un ordenamiento ;)

Comment: Okey, entiendo, ya se lo que debo hacer, estaré repasando como hacer un ordenamiento y cualquier cosa añadiré un comentario en esta pregunta para resolver una duda. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Samuel, tienes muchos algoritmos para ordenar un contenedor, podrías usar el clásico y simple [ordenamiento de burbuja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja) y una lista intermedia para almacenar los caracteres, se puede implementar prácticamente con las mismas linea que tienes ahora.

Comment: Tengo una duda, respecto al ordenamiento de burbuja, ¿Este trabaja exclusivamente con listas? ¿O puedo hacerlo directamente sobre la cadena?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo sobre cadenas directamente, pero como son inmutables tienes que crear una nueva cada vez que intercambias y es un peñazo además de ineficiente cuando usando una lista es tan simple como `lista[n], lista[m] = lista[m], lista[n]`. Si no te prohíben usar listas convertir la cadena a una lista de caracteres sería lo normal. `list(cadena)`. De cualquier forma este problema lo tienes uses el método que uses, me parecería estúpido evitar que se usen listas, pero bueno si no te dejan no puedes hacer nada, tendrás que implementar un método feo e ineficente concatenado cadenas...XD

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda colega, gracias a tus consejos hice el código que publiqué como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def ordenar_cadenav4(cadena:str)->list:
        lista_cadena=list(cadena)
        esta_desordenado=False
        while esta_desordenado==False:
            esta_desordenado=True
            for arreglo in range(len(lista_cadena)-1):
                if lista_cadena[arreglo]>lista_cadena[arreglo+1]:
                    elemento_mayor=lista_cadena[arreglo]
                    lista_cadena[arreglo]=lista_cadena[arreglo+1]
                    lista_cadena[arreglo+1]=elemento_mayor
                    esta_desordenado=False
    return "".join(lista_cadena)
```

Este es el código solución al problema, y como me indicaron las personas que comentaron m pregunta usé el ordenamiento de burbuja para solucionarlo. Gracias a FJSevilla y gbianchi que me ayudaron en la solución del código.